# How do I create a cron to find and delete directories that are 90 days old but ignore 2 sub-directories?

Tags: debian, find, cron, path, rm

### What I have

I have a cron currently setup that finds and deletes directories & files that are 90 days old

### What I need

I would like the crontab to ignore two directories when deleting directories & files over 90 days old

### What I have done so far

This crontab removes directories & files and ignores dir1, but still removes directories & files from dir2, even though I have it specified in the second -not -path.

```
00 4 * * * sudo find /home/*/* -type d -not -path "/home/dir1/*" -not -path "/home/dir2/*" -mtime +90 -exec rm -r "{}" \;
02 4 * * * sudo find /home/*/* -type f -not -path "/home/dir1/*" -not -path "/home/dir2/*" -mtime +90 -exec rm "{}" \;
```

### The actual question

How is it possible to ignore two directories when finding and deleting directories / files, do you simply specify -not -path twice as I cannot get this to work as per the example above?

Comment: That find is fine to my eyes. Have you tried removing the `-mtime` filter and testing it a directory structure to see if the filtering is OK? That may be a good way to go about debugging it.

Answer (score 0):

First, the `crontab` command field is NOT `bash`. You should invoke a `bash` script stored elsewhere, rather than misusing the command field.

Read `man find xargs`, and

```
#!/bin/bash
find /home/*/* -type d \( -name dir1 -o -name dir2 \) -prune -type f -mtime +60 -print0 | \
  xargs -0 -r rm
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it put me on the right path. A slight modification, as to exclude we require ! and I've specified path names, as such `#!/bin/bash
find /home/*/* ! \( -path "/home/dir1/*" -o -path "/home/dir2/*" \) -prune -type f,d -mtime +90 -print0 | \
  xargs -0 -r rm`